# Is there any difference between nvprof and pgprof?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, pgi

I am interested to know if `pgprof` == `nvprof`+`nvvp`. 
For instance, I would like to know if they are interchangable. `nvprof` or `nvvp` will profile a PGI OpenACC application exactly as `pgprof`?
For instance, `pgprof` preselects the CUDA toolkit that comes with the OpenACC installation, and `nvvp` selects the the one in `/usr/local/cuda`. There is any problem on mixing the toolkits?

I'm a bit confused because the documentation of both tools ([NVIDIA Profiler documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) & [PGI Profiler Guide](https://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs/17.10/openpower/profiler-users-guide/index.htm)) looks exactly the same.

Also doing a diff doesn't show any clear difference:

```
$ nvprof --help > help.nv
$ pgprof --help > help.pgi
$ diff help.pgi help.nv
1c1
< Usage: pgprof [options] [application] [application-arguments]
---
> Usage: nvprof [options] [application] [application-arguments]
113c113
<                         this pgprof instance. Note: Only one instance of pgprof
---
>                         this nvprof instance. Note: Only one instance of nvprof
305c305
<                         Suppress all pgprof output.
---
>                         Suppress all nvprof output.
346c346
<                         Make pgprof send all its output to the specified file, or
---
>                         Make nvprof send all its output to the specified file, o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When NVIDIA acquired PGI a few years ago, we did merge pgprof and nvprof with pgprof's CPU profiling brought into nvprof.  The main difference is that pgprof will enable CPU profiling by default while this need to be enabled via the "--cpu-profiling on" option when using nvprof.